# Angular 2, all in one file?

Tags: angularjs, compilation, combinations

I am new to Angular. I passed the "Tour of Heroes: the vision" tutorial. In the end i got working app, it's all cool but one thing make me go mad!

[image]

334 requests and 7.6s loading!

My question is how to combine all that angular components in one file and tell angular not to load them all?

Thank in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Browsers has limitation on request count, [see](https://stackoverflow.com/q/985431/492258)

You can use [gulp-concat](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-concat) to unify files into a single file

Comment: Ok, but how to collect such files:

http://localhost:3000/js/node_modules/@angular/platform-browser/src/browser/location/browser_platform_location.js

http://localhost:3000/node_modules/@angular/compiler/src/view_compiler/expression_converter.js

There are many nested sub folders.

Comment: npm modules are not required to be included to unified file

Answer (score 0):

I found this CDN- https://cdnjs.com/libraries/angular.js/

Why not only use the components you need and also the above cdn has minified versions.